# Changed Fullname and Account name but not Home directory, now blank "Admin" page

Tags: macos, preferences, administrator

This morning i changed the Full name and Account name on my account but not home directory name. Now, everytime an admin feature is needed, it just shows up as a blank login page. When i try to right click in "User & groups" for advanced options, nothing happens.

Im still able to login into the computer but it shows a totatlly different name from what i changed it to. Do i have to reinstall mac??

Also, ANY info i put into the blank admin field comes up incorrect.

[image: login]

Comment: Question is totally different, but you are in the same situation, your account has been demoted to a standard account.

Comment: how do i fix it ??

Comment: See the answer on the linked question.

Comment: These solutions dont work. I tried resetting password and everything, I think i need to rename the user somehow.